# Redirect in Application_Error after an HttpRequestValidationException

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on an asp.net mvc 4.0 application and I have a couple of `<form>` tags here and there … of course, when I intentionally enter HTML tags in the textboxes, I get the following `HttpRequestValidationException` exception with the following message:

*`A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client…`*

My goal is **NOT** to allow malicious script, tags or whatever to be entered (so , I will **NOT** be using the `[AllowHtml]` attribute on my properties.).

Instead, what I would like to do is to redirect the user to a specific page telling them that “*we’ve detected malicious script(s) …blah blah blah*”.

Because of the exception, my Controller’s ActionResult is not being invoked, this means I have to handle this inside the Application_Error() method of the Global.asax.

My question is the following:

How do I redirect the user to a particular Controller (and ActionResult) when I get an `HttpRequestValidationException` ?

So far, I have the following:

```
HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;

if (httpException is HttpRequestValidationException)
{
    //FIXME...Redirect to the ErrorController-->InvalidInput() ActionResult
}
```

How do I acheive the redirect?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (httpException is HttpRequestValidationException)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/error/InvalidInput");
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, perhaps I'll change my approach and create some sort of ActionFilter that will handle this instead of cluttering the Application_Error() with that type of code.

Comment: This doesn't maintain Session variables :/